# how to localize app title in mac pkg

Tags: macos, localization, title, pkg-file

I'm creating an app to run on Macbooks.  I have successfully localized my app title using the `Info.plist` and `Infoplist.strings` so when it is installed, the localized title is displayed correctly in the Applications folder, and when I run the app, the localized title appears correctly in the menu bar.

However, when I run my package to install my app, everything appears to be localized automatically in the installer EXCEPT my app title.  How can I get my app title to be localized in the installer?